# Open a PDF existing file then save it in to a specific folder in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file, pdf, io

I have existing code here, but it shows a SaveAs dialog immediately and this is quite confusing for some users. How can I improve this?

```
Dim write As StreamWriter
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF Files |*.pdf"
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
write = File.AppendText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
write.WriteLine()
write.Close()
```

Comment: What is your exact request?

Comment: open a pdf file first then save it. in the code that I have it immediately open the saves as dialog window so i need to choose the file , highlight it then select the destination folder. However, my users tend to duplicate the file in the location of the file folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want us to help you change how the user interface works, we need to see more context from that interface, and you need to talk to your users more about what they expected instead of the SaveAs dialog.

But we can help improve this code some:

```
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF Files |*.pdf"
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(SaveFileDialog1.FileName) Then    
    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName) 
        writer.WriteLine()
    End Using
End If
```

Based on the question title, maybe you wanted to show an `OpenFileDialog` first? Have you tried that? And then maybe a `FolderBrowserDialog` instead of `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: yes. I want to use opendialog first then save the file in my destination folder that I want.I will try that folderbrowserdialog